# Target two siblings of input:checked

Tags: css

I'm trying to style two siblings -- a span and a div -- of input:checked like this...

```
input:checked + span {styles}

input:checked + div {styles}
```

Not working... What am I missing?

Comment: are they really siblings in the DOM?

Comment: Please post HTML, problem is there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM structure is the problem. `<span>` and `<div>` are probably not sibling to inputs but css is fine. Here is example of how sibling of inputs work:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" checked/>
<span>span</span>
<input type="radio" name="group1" />
<div>div</div>
```

And css:

```
input:checked + span {color:red;}

input:checked + div {color:red;}
```

And here is JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/marszurgot/yawksjvj/

Comment: Got it. I used "+" for the adjacent sibling and "~" for the not-adjacent one. Thanks!